# Delete from table B where value does not exists in Table A

Tags: mysql

I am trying to accomplish the following in MySQL:

```
delete from table_b where table_b.token is not found in table_a.token
```

Explanation:

Both tables have a column called **`token`**.

I want to delete all records on table_b if `token` in table_b does not exist in the `token` 
column in table_a.

Comment: Thanks, both. The suggestion from mti2935 worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a subquery:

```
delete from table_b where token not in (select token from table_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join

```
delete b.*
from table_b b
left join table_a a on(b.token = a.token)
where a.token is null
```